# What is WSDL? Web Services Definition Language

Tags: wsdl

I am new in salesforce and Web services, I have read some articles and theres this WSDL. I searched for it coz I dont understand it. Can you please explain its purpose?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl - It is not unique to SF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, a webservice is used to send data, over web to any destination.

SOAP is one of the protocols (set of rules) which defines the communication. There are others as well.

WSDL is the way you (web service creator) tell users (who use web services) :-

1. what to send
2. how to send
3. where to send

I will recommend reading articles around SOAP, WSDL on wikipedia which can give you lots of insights around this.